# Accessing Text Label Value Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have a piece of java script that makes a table of cells where each cell has an ordered list of its number, a label, and a text box. A snippet of this code is written below:

```
<table id="drawAllQuestionsTbl">
<tbody><tr><td class="tbl">
<ol start="1">
<li>Sport 1:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tq_g_0_guess" size="15"></li></ol></td></tr><tr><td class="tbl">
```

For brevity, I cut a lot of the extra stuff. In reality, this table is filled with around 10 replicas of this cell, where each cell has an ordered list with a label and text box. For the text box in this ordered list for instance, I can successfully access its value using `document.getElementsByName("tq_g_0_guess")`. However, my question is how to get the value of the label "Sport 1" next to this text box. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have control over the outputted HTML? If it was in an actual `label` tag, then it would be much easier.

Comment: I wish, but unfortunately I do not. I am trying to strip this content off a web page.

Comment: What versions of IE are you concerned with?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you the text of the `li` node. This will be `Sport 1:`.

```
var elParent = document.getElementsByName("tq_g_0_guess")[0].parentNode;
var labelText = elParent.innerText;
console.log(labelText); // Sport 1:
```

You can leverage `labelText` to further format the text to the desired result.

If you *only* want `Sport 1`, then you can substring the everything up to the colon

```
labelText.substr(0, labelText.indexOf(':'));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
document.getElementsByName("tq_g_0_guess")[0].parentNode.innerText
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

writing in JavaScript:

```
var child = document.getElementsByName("tq_g_0_guess")[0]; // ok, must add a [0] after this.
var preTextNode = child.previousSibling;
var textContent = preTextNode.textContent; // this is the text you want.
```

Comment: This does not work... `child` returns a nodeList. Therefore you must target an item within that node list.

Comment: thanks, I seldom use getElementsByName, so I take it as getElementById.

Comment: Yeah it's not used often anymore. But, usually the method name hints at the returned value. `getElement...` vs `getElements...` or `querySelector` vs `querySelectorAll`

Comment: yes. I turned to **querySelector** & **querySelectorAll** once I know how to use them to deal with DOM elements. And they act more like **jQuery('selector')**.